# How to change DateTime format on Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, datetime, highcharts, datetime-format

I have datetime data on json look like this : "timestamp": "2020-03-15T11:46:10+07:00".
How can i change date format into HH:mm on highcharts? This is my code : https://jsfiddle.net/estri012/q89vt1j0/13/
But it seems didn't work. Date format won't change.

```
Highcharts.getJSON('https://gmlews.com/api/data', function (data) {
console.log(data);
var accelero_x = [], timestamp = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
accelero_x.push(data[i].accelero_x);
timestamp.push(data[i].timestamp);
}
console.log(accelero_x);
console.log(timestamp);

// Create the chart
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: {
  type: 'spline',
  renderTo: 'container'
},
title: {
  text: 'Coba'
},
tooltip: {
  valueDecimals: 2
},
subtitle: {
  text: 'Accelero X'
},
xAxis: {
    type: "datetime",
  categories: timestamp,
  labels: {
        format: '{value:%Y-%m-%d}',
        rotation: 45,
        align: 'left'
    }

},
series: [{
  data: accelero_x //
}]
});
});
```

Update : I update my code here http://jsfiddle.net/estri012/b5nhezLs/8/
And the new proble is my timestamp look like this "2020-03-15T11:46:10+07:00". So on the chart it should shows 15 March 11:46 instead of 15 March 04:46. The chart show UTC time. How to fix it, so the chart show the same time with mine?
And the last three data on the chart show 18 March instead of 19 March. In my API https://gmlews.com/api/data , the last three data must be 19 March not 18 March

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this for formatting

```
formatter: (currData) => {
     const currDate = new Date(currData.value);
     return currDate.getHours() + ':' + currDate.getMinutes();
},
```

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/5hupyv8m/1/

Or

simply update the for loop for x axis labels

Like

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    accelero_x.push(data[i].accelero_x);
    const currTimeStamp = new Date(data[i].timestamp);
    timestamp.push(currTimeStamp.getHours() + ':' + currTimeStamp.getMinutes());
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4poc6re7/

Update

You can use this function for converting time in `hh:mm` format

```
 function format_two_digits(n) {
   return n < 10 ? '0' + n : n;
 }
```

Updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/4poc6re7/1/

Comment: When it is 13:10 it appears 13:0, why it looks like that?

Comment: this is happen to 07:00 as well

Comment: @Estri.PLestari example timestamp? Did you mean when timestamp is something 13:10, its showing 13:0 on chart?

Comment: Can you post example timestamp?

Comment: 2020-03-16T07:00:00+07:00

Comment: btw, I check again your fiddle and do you know why this is happen? In the three last data on the chart it is shows 18 March, but actually in the API the data is from 19 March. The other data showing the right datetime. Just those data which showing wrong date.

Answer (score 2):

As highcharts has a built in formatter for dates: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts#.dateFormat

I would suggest doing it this way:

You need to convert the timestamp string to a date format using `Date.parse()`.

After defining your array, change (or redefine if you want) it to dates, by mapping all values to a date using Date.parse (or do this as you load the array):

```
timestamp = timestamp.map(x=>Date.parse(x))
```

and then the standard formatting should work, you just need to change it to time. In my example I've changed it to "day hours:minutes:seconds"

```
format: '{value:%d %H:%M:%S}'
```

Working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pqocv312/

Comment: Thankyou, you help me a lot!

Comment: btw, I check again your fiddle and do you know why this is happen? In the three last data on the chart it is shows 18 March, but actually in the API the data is from 19 March. The other data showing the right datetime. Just those data which showing wrong date.

Comment: oh and there is it the time shows like this : 2020-03-15T11:46:10+07:00 . In the chart it should be 11:46, but it shows 04:46. How to fix it?

Comment: It's because the timezone information is included in the timestamp, and the chart is showing the UTC value. It's worth raising that as a new question here, rather than a comment.